# Bitwise operators, why does adding 1 to a binary number that has had a NOT operator applied to it make it negative and not a different number?

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation

I'm just starting down the path of learning about Bitwise operators (although I'm struggling to find any absolute beginner resources). I understand how binary works and how to read it but I don't understand the following.

If you take the number 37 in binary:
`00100101` and apply the ~(NOT) operator to it, the bits get flipped to
`11011010`
In the tutorial I am reading it says you must add a one to it as a sort of flag to signal it is negative. So it becomes `11011011`. I don't understand why this new number isn't just read as 219.

On a related note does anyone have any in depth, explain everything resource that I can use to really get my head into all of this and eventually make sense of it all?

Comment: `a - b` is equivalent to `a + ~b + 1`, so `0 - x` is equivalent to `~x + 1`. Alternatively, `a - b` is also equivalent to `~(~a + b)`, so `0 - x` is equivalent to `~(x - 1)`. Also, consider this: if you add `~x` to `x` you'd get "all ones", so if you added *one more*, you'd get zero. Adding two things and getting zero means they were each other negatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to "I don't understand why this new number isn't just read as 219" really must be "because the interpretation of the bits is known to be signed, and use 2s complement".

Bits are just bits, you have to specify an interpretation in order to apply rules such as the ones you're referencing.

If the number is considered to be an unsigned integer, then it should be converted to 219 in decimal. If it's considered a signed integer, then it should be converted to -37.

You can easily try this by running [this little C program](http://ideone.com/yv3a9R):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  const int x = 37;
  const int y = ~x + 1;

  printf("%d or %u?\n", y, y & 255);

  return 0;
}
```

It prints "-37 or 219?" since the interpretation of the bits is different in the two cases. The `& 255` part is just to cut out the higher-valued bits since they otherwise make it quite confusing (C's `int` integer type is larger than 8 bits).

Comment: Does this mean then that the right most binary digit is a flag to indicate negative numbers and the second digit from the right now represents the number 1 instead?

Answer (score 5):

A [bitwise NOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_NOT#NOT) is also known as a [1s complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1s_complement).

You can convert a 1s complement number to [2s complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) by adding 1.

Both 1s complement and 2s complement are different ways of representing negative numbers, but these days 2s complement is almost universally used.

So, to negate a number in 2s complement form you can simply apply a bitwise NOT and add 1, i.e.

```
-x == ~x + 1
```

Conversely, to convert a 2s complement number to 1s complement you can negate it and subtract 1:

```
~x == -x - 1
```

Note that positive numbers have the same representation in 1s complement and 2s complement representations - it is only negative numbers for which there is a difference. E.g. for 8 bit integer:

```
Decimal    1s complement    2s complement
      0         00000000         00000000
     -0         11111111              n/a
      1         00000001         00000001
     -1         11111110         11111111
      2         00000010         00000010
     -2         11111101         11111110
    127         01111111         01111111
   -127         10000000         10000001
   -128              n/a         10000000
```

Note that 1s complement has two representations for decimal 0: +0 and -0, while 2s complement has a unique zero representation. 2s complement can also represent an additional negative value that is not available in 1s complement (-128 in the case of 8 bit integers).

Comment: Thank you Paul. I have seen 1s and 2s complements being mentioned a lot in the few hours worth of research I've done so I will certainly give them a look in.